# Portability of iterating over an array using a pointer

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

Will the following assertion always be true regardless of the platform, and do you have a reference for this guarantee?

```
const unsigned SIZE = 10;
Foo array[SIZE];
Foo* ptr = array;
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
    assert(&array[i] == (ptr + i));
}
```

Edit:
To clarify the question, a for loop can be used to iterate over the elements of an array in the following ways:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i) {
   DoSomethingWith(array[i]);
}


Foo* end = array + array_size;
for (Foo* ptr = array; ptr < end; ++ptr) {
   DoSomethingWith(*ptr);
}
```

My understanding is that not all architectures use the same order when addressing memory, so I was curious about the portability of the pointer method. If you were to search this website for the use of "iterate array with pointer" or mistakenly include endian in the search, nothing relevant appears.

Comment: Yes it will always be true.  Did you have trouble finding a reference yourself?  Where did you try to look (there are SO answers with links to final-draft C, C++03 and C++11 Standards), and how did you get stuck...?  Downvote for "this question does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ standard, section § 5.2.2 [expr.sub] :

> The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))

So `array[i]` is identical to `*(array + i)`

Since `ptr == array` it is also `*(ptr + i)`

So, `&array[i]` is `&(*(ptr + i))`, which is `(ptr + i)`

---

**Note:**

This is assuming that you did not override `Foo::operator &` : if so, the result of `&(*(ptr + i))` might not be `(ptr + i)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 : true, note added.